# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json エラーが発生する

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

AWS LambdaでC#でJsonを返すWebApiを作成しています。
NugetパッケージマネージャでNewtonsoft.Jsonのv13.0.2を参照して以下のコードをAWSの
Lambmaで動作させるとエラーメッセージが発生しました。

Nugetのコンソールマネージャからインストールしたのは
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json、Newtonsoft.Jsonの二つです。
解決するための手段などお教えいただけないでしょうか。
C#のランタイムは.Net6です。

（追記）
上記の質問を投稿した後に新たに分かったことですが、
上記の事象はデプロイ方法はVisualStudio2022と.NET Core CLIのどちらでも試しました。
どちらでもConfigurationをDebugにした時に発生しており、
試しにReleaseに設定すると上記のエラーが発生せずに正常にデプロイ、
動作することがわかりました。

エラーメッセージ:

```js
  "errorType": "FileNotFoundException",
  "errorMessage": "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified.\n",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)",
    "at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.<get_Signature>g__LazyCreateSignature|19_0()",
    "at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()",
    "at System.RuntimeType.FilterApplyMethodBase(MethodBase methodBase, BindingFlags methodFlags, BindingFlags bindingFlags, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] argumentTypes)",
    "at System.RuntimeType.GetConstructorCandidates(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, Boolean allowPrefixLookup)",
    "at System.RuntimeType.GetConstructorImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConvention, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)",
    "at System.Type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConvention, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)",
    "at System.Type.GetConstructor(Type[] types)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeLoader.ConstructCustomSerializer(Attribute serializerAttribute) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs:line 360",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeLoader.GetSerializerObject(Assembly customerAssembly) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs:line 216",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeLoader.Init(Action`1 customerLoggingAction) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs:line 124",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeInitializer.InitializeAsync() in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeInitializer.cs:line 46",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InitializeAsync() in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/LambdaBootstrap.cs:line 155"
  ]
```

ソースコード:

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;

[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace XXXX_SITE_TEST_Lambda1
{
    public class Function
    {
        public LambdaResponse FunctionHandler(object input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            var body = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "message", "Hello, World" },
            };

            var response = new LambdaResponse()
            {
                isBase64Encoded = false,
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                headers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    {"my_header", "my_value" }
                },
                body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body),
            };

            return response;
        }

        public class LambdaResponse
        {
            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "isBase64Encoded")]
            public bool isBase64Encoded;

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "statusCode")]
            public HttpStatusCode statusCode;

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "headers")]
            public Dictionary<string, string> headers;

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "body")]
            public string body;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: デプロイ手順に問題があり必要なアセンブリが含まれなかったのだと思いますが、肝心の手順が書かれていないので原因はわからないです。どのような手順を行ったのかを記載してください。

Comment: デプロイ方法はVisualStudio2022と.NET Core CLIのどちらでも試しました。
どちらでもConfigurationをDebugにした時に発生しており、
試しにReleaseに設定すると上記のエラーが発生せずに正常にデプロイ、
動作することがわかりました。

Comment: そう質問文に書いてください。